# Dynamic SQL query Issue - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a dynamic query for paging purpose. below is the last part of the executable query and when i print it and run in different window it works fine. but when i use **exec** it shows red squiggle for casting parts (CAST(@pint_StartRowIndex AS VARCHAR)) as showing in attached image.

could anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? If i use **Print** instead of **Exec** it gives no errors and printed query execute with no errors.

[image]

Comment: Build your command first and  then pass it to exec, i.e. `declare @sqlcommand nvarchar(max);set @sqlcommand = 'this ' + that; exec(@sqlcommand)`

Comment: @artm i did it at first place. But there will be additional where conditions to the query. in this case i used minimum conditions. as i know varchar(max) can hold only 8000 characters. i have doubt that with additional conditions this limit might exceed. That's why i tried to execute as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this :

```
exec ('SELECT * from table where Rank BETWEEN CAST ('+ @start + 'as nvarchar)' + ' AND cast (' +  @end + 'as nvarchar)')
```

quote everything  as string except @start and @end